# How can I display AlbumArt in the foobar2000 notification balloon?

Tags: windows, foobar2000, notification-area

I'm using foobar2000 1.1.6 and Columns UI 0.3.8.6.

Is there a way (e.g. using variables) to display AlbumArt for the currently playing track in foobar2000's notification balloon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in a comment upper, foo_popupplus has the undesirable effect of crashing my foobar2000, which is not a tolerable behaviour. As a consequence, i investiguated a little further and found out [foobar-gntp](http://dimovski.se/foobar-gntp/download.php). Already using [Growl for Windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/), it made sense for me to use a centralized notification system, even if it is not the classical notification baloon of Windows.

Unfortunatly, it is not a direct solution to my initial issue.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I'm sorry. I've missed reading 'columnsUI' in your question. My answer is providing another solution. I will leave it anyway, maybe it will help someone else.

---

Try [foo_popupplus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/foopopupplus/):

[image]

foo_popupplus provides:

- Fully customizable (skin, font)
- Skinnable
- Action buttons

Reference: [Notification: A nice popup in the corner](http://winamp2foobar.blogspot.com/2008/09/nice-popup-in-corner.html)

Comment: Indeed, you missed the point of ColumnsUI. Anyway, I'll take a look at it, and if it fits my need, well, that's a solution ..

Comment: Unfortunatly, launching this old plugin on my new foobar20000 1.1.6 crashed it, so direct to the trash.

Comment: Sorry for that. But I couldn't find any other solutions apart from that.

Comment: Yes, Indeed. I have found a solution that I'll add here, but it requires growl, so out of direct scope (but you diserve an upvote).